# How to show additional details in shopify admin order?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am creating an app in Shopify where I have to add additional fields to Shopify and show these fields in the Shopify order admin page. Please guide me to complete this task.
Please see screenshot http://prntscr.com/fsqiux

Thanks

Comment: As far i know you can not put anything directly in that page. I might be wrong. 
https://freakdesign.com.au/pages/shopify-custom-fields this chrome addon may help.
again I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in Shopify to extend the admin page. If you need to store additional info to an object, for example an order, you can use metafields. What you can do with Metafield and all resources are explained at https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/metafield

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by setting cart attributes. No need to create an app.

[Documentation](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/cart/get-more-information-with-cart-attributes)

For example, you can use the following code.

```
<p class="cart-attribute__field">
  <label for="new-attribute">New Attribute</label>
  <input id="new-attribute" type="text" name="attributes[New Attribute]" value="{{ cart.attributes["New Attribute"] }}">
</p>
```